# How to remove item from request class Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to remove `slug` from `$request` when I'm **updating record** and new `slug` equals to old `slug`! (Because I use `$request->validate()` to check if slug is unique in table but it fails!)

Comment: You can update your unique validation so that it ignores the record being updated when checking uniqueness. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without removing the field. For example, if you're using validation request, you can ignore the unique-checking like this:

```
// don't forget to use this in the top of your class-file
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    // for your case replace the word "post"s if need for your appropriate table
    return [
        'slug' => ['required', Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($this->post()->id)]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! we can use

`$request->request->remove('slug');`